# How to run chrome from terminal window after deb isntallation?

Tags: chrome, remote-desktop

I have remote box accessed by VNC and `jwm` desktop. No menus, not desktop icons, only terminal window.

I have downloaded `chrome` deb package and installed it. Now how can I run it from terminal window?

Answer (score 2):

Run the command `locate chrome` to see all the occurrences of chrome within the filesystem (file & directory names). On **Ubuntu 12.04 & 12.10** I have it installed here: `/opt/google/chrome`.

You can run it using any of these methods:

- `/opt/google/chrome/chrome`
- `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`

If `/opt/google/chrome` is on the `PATH` then you can drop the path part and just run `chrome` or `google-chrome`.

**NOTE:** `google-chrome` is a shell script that wraps the executable `chrome` so I'd be inclined to run that.

To see if something is on the `PATH` run this command:

```
% echo $PATH
/opt/google/chrome:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `dpkg -L /path/to/google-chrome-VERSION.deb` to see the list of files in the package. To see the list of directly-executable commands it provides, run

```
dpkg -L /path/to/google-chrome-VERSION.deb | grep /bin/
```

If you installed the package through `apt-get`, Aptitude, Synaptic or the like, the `.deb` file is in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

The name of the program in the official Chrome packages is `google-chrome` (`/usr/bin/google-chrome` is a symbolic link to `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`).

If typing the command `google-chrome` in a shell doesn't work immediately after installing the package, you may need to run `hash -r` to tell your shell to flush its cache of known commands. This only applies in shells that were already running before you installed the package.